# Are vertex shader programs computed per-fragment, or are they simply interpolated?

Tags: shader

I imagine Direct3D and OpenGL work the same way in this regard, so I won't specify an api.

Behind the scenes, are the vertex shader output structures interpolated upon being passed to the fragment shader, or is the shader itself interpolated (run multiple times) with intermediate values?

If one has a relatively expensive fragment shader and a small number of vertices to process, will moving some of that code to the vertex shader help performance?

Answer (score 0):

Fragment shader called for each pixel on the screen after rasterization, so yes moving some code to vertex shader will improve perfomance. But some time effect will much vorse. For example light spot with lowpoly mesh will look very ugly, or could even be unnoticable if spot can fit in single triangle, have a look [here](http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/per-vertex-lighting/).

Have a look at this [OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview) for better understanding of rendering pipeline.